# how do you remove a stripped screw that holds the handle on outdoor faucet

Tags: plumbing

I am trying to replace washers on an outdoor faucet but the screw holding the handle on is stripped.

Also apparently stucco is all holding the PVC pipe to the faucet on the wall.

How do I tighten that up? Is there some sort of cement I can use?

Comment: A small screw extractor tool should do the job, if not use a drill slightly larger than the screw shank to cut the head off. There should be enough remaining shank after handle removal to grab a hold with locking pliers. You could try construction adhesive or epoxy, but you really want a flanged sill cock anchored into solid wood.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to deal with this is to use a Dremel rotary tool and an abrasive wheel to cut a slot in the fastener. You can then use a screwdriver to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use some solder to fill the hole and solder a screwdriver to the screw and gently work it out. Once its out you can just reheat the solder to clean off the screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

OK - for a REALLY FROZEN spigot handle screw:  I tried all of the methods a read about on-line > heating faucet w/heat gun and putting ice on the screw after applying WD-40 and tapping on the screw (even let lubricant sit overnight), using a screw extractor - and, what seemed like the best solution > using a rotary tool to cut a longer/deeper slot in the head of the screw and using a flat-head screwdriver.  Only problem was - I cut the slot too deep (N.B.) and when I turned the screwdriver, half the screw head broke off.  After pondering/swearing and pounding on the handle with a hammer some more - just for good measure - I realized I should be able to pull the handle off completely - now that the head of screw had been removed.  Only problem was the tube of the handle was also frozen to the top of the valve stem!!!  After multiple unsuccessful attempts to dislodge it with the hammer - I was finally able to pry it off with the claw end of a nail hammer. There was then enough of the top of the screw exposed that I was able to grab it with a pair of vice-grips and unscrew it (after applying more WD-40 of course).  Hope this is helpful to someone.